# Rim cement as a replacement for rubber cement

Tags: repair, innertube, puncture

Can I use aluminium rim cement for patching flat tire instead of using rubber cement?

Comment: I doubt if it would work very well.

Comment: is your tire made of aluminium?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. For patching punctured innertubes, you must use vulcanizing [rubber cement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_cement). [Vulcanization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcanization) which crosslinks the polymers in the tube with those in the patch. Most types of rubber cement, which are used for crafts, are not vulcanizing. Aluminum rim cement is designed to bond aluminum, not to vulcanize rubber.

Answer (score 3):

I have used rim cement or vulcanising cement without thinking about it for 50 years and noticed no problems. Interested in the expert advice that rim cement does not fuse the surfaces properly, so this week I stuck a patch on a butyl tube with Conti Rim cement , using a very thin smear, almost dry , then pressed a patch on firmly. After an hour I could not peel the patch off. It is fused on just as with vulcanising cement. I did sand clean the area before applying cement.

So since I have a lot of Conti Rim cement I will carry on using it. Thin smear of cement.

In the past I have had pre-glued patches melt off on long hilly days, so stopped using them. I used to cut a bit of old tube to use as a patch but you have to clean and roughen it well or it doesn't stick, and patches are very cheap.. As a child I used duct tape or even bubble gum and while they cannot be recommended they worked well enough.